# document.write inside iframe is rendering a blank page in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I want to render responsetext in my document which is inside an iframe. I am using document.write(responsetext) which works fine for all browsers except IE11.

Is there any alternative or workaround for this?

Also, it works fine in IE if this is done outside iframe.

The following code snippet is submitting a form using Ajax Post request.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
            method: 'POST',
            url: g_globalsFromJsp.contextPath + '/UploadAction0.do',
            params: formData,
            success: function (response, opts) {
                        if (response.status ===200) { // OK
                            //Error Here
                            document.open();
                            document.write(response.responseText);
                            document.close();
                        }
            },
            failure : function(response, opts) {
                //SomeAlertMessage
            }
        })
```

Edit:
There are two different web pages involved in my issue.  I will call them P1 and P2. P2 contains the above-mentioned code snippet and works fine independently. But When P2 is called from an iframe inside P1 the iframe goes blank in IE11. Also from P2 I cannot access the iframe.

Comment: That can't be true, `dw` in an ajax callback would wipe out the current document in any browser.

Comment: Unfortunately it is happening in my case

Comment: No, I can't belive this, caching, something overrides `dw` in other browsers ... anything but the way you've described. It is just not possible. Please show the code you have.

Comment: @AnkitBansal Do you have a sample somewhere which we can open in IE and Chrome to see for ourselves?

Comment: @Alexander I will try to generate a sample in some time, I don't have ready-made sample

Comment: Your code should simply clear the document where the script is run, unless there's some wicked hidden code, which redefines `document` and/or its [`write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) method. And this happens in all browsers, not only in IE.

Comment: The code ofcourse should create new content to the new document. If it doesn't in IE, you should take a carefull look into the HTML you're trying to write to the file. IE has some issues concerning invalid HTML (among other issues it has).

Comment: When I am commenting out document.open() IE is rendering the page, although not exactly same as other browsers. Not able to understand the reason behind it.

Comment: `document.write` calls `open()` implicitly when it is called after the pages has been parsed, hence calling it explicitly is not needed (in any browser). It shouldn't have any affect to the execution, though. Diffrerent rendering is a trademark of IE, if you've issues with that, you should post a new question.

Comment: @AnkitBansal, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: If you are using `document.open()` before `document.write()` like I did try removing that